# How do I interpret this Namespaced Schema Def?

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm working with an XSD and don't understand the implications of the namespaces it defines. Here's the piece I'm trying to interpret:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<xs:schema
  targetNamespace      ="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
  elementFormDefault   ="qualified"
  xmlns                ="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
  xmlns:mstns          ="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
  xmlns:xs             ="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>
```

The definition that follows is a single root element of complexType, which is set of elements that include a mix of simple and complex types.

```
<xs:element name = "RootElement" type = "rootelement"></xs:element>

<xs:complexType name = "rootlement">
  <xs:sequence>
  .
  .
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

The most basic thing I don't get is why, when I process this XSD using CAM for example, all the elements are prefixed with 'mstns'. Why 'mstns'? All elements and sub-elements are prefixed with 'xs' in the definition itself.

The second thing I'm not getting is why, when I process the XSD using XML::Compile, template() says it is unable to find RootElement (no matter whether I prefix it or not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The types and elements defined in your schema belong to your `targetNamespace`. That means that if you want to validate `<RootElement>` in a XML file:

```
<RootElement> ... </RootElement>
```

It needs to declare that namespace:

```
<RootElement xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"> ... </RootElement>
```

Otherwise it belongs in *no-namespace* and your processor will be unable to find it.

In your Schema document, the `"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"` namespace is associated to a prefix (`xs` in your document, which is a convention) so you can use the elements, attributes and types from the XML Schema vocabulary and not mix them up with the elements, attributes and types that you are defining. In your schema, your *default* namespace is assigned to your `targetNamespace`, which is also a convention. You *could* legally invert that (although you would be breaking these conventions), declaring the  `"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"` namespace as the *default* one, and prefixing your `targetNamespace`:

```
<schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd" 
        xmlns:myprefix="http://tempuri.org/XMLShema.xsd"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

which would allow you to declare `<element>` without a prefix, *but* now you will have to qualify your types, since you can no longer refer to your target namespace as default:

```
<element name="RootElement" type="myprefix:rootelement"/>
```

In your schema you have two mappings for your target namespace. One as the default namespace, and another with the prefix `mstns`. Usually that is necessary if you have XPath expressions in your schema (ex: keys, unique constraints). XPath required that selectors be prefixed. So, to be able to use unprefixed types and also to be able to use XPath, its convenient to associate your namespace to a prefix as well.

The prefix has a local scope. You can choose any prefix you want (except 'xml') and it can be different in the XML instances you wish to validate. In your XML instance, you can declare a default namespace as shown above, and also could validate your document using any prefix:

```
<myprefix:RootElement xmlns:myprefix="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd">
 ... </myprefix:RootElement>
```

So it doesn't matter if your elements have a prefix or not, as long as the namespace associated to the prefix or the default namespace are your target namespace.

Comment: I have a feeling I'm not ever going to get this.

Comment: Perhaps you should first try to understand well how namespaces work in XML. Once you understand that, it becomes much easier to understand how XSD deals with it.

Comment: Agreed, of course. Unfortunately for me it's iterative--complete understanding eludes me without examples, examples make no sense without some understanding. Seems like a simple concept that isn't really anything new--but then I have this example where CAM interprets the XSD in a way that puts everything in the mstns namespace. It's utterly unclear why, to me. Among many other things, the relationship between scope and membership isn't clear at all. Four or five other resources and a lot of work, and I'm sure your explanation will be clear. And thanks for taking the time.

Comment: This is a very good tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468565.aspx It starts with the reasons namespaces are used in programming languages in general, and then explains how it is used in XML with very simple examples. If you can dedicate some 20-30 minutes to it, I'm sure everything will become much clearer.

Comment: Starting to make some sense--thanks both for the answer and the link; together I'm starting to crack the code a bit.